# HTML navigation bar on right hand side of page

Tags: html, css

I want a navigation bar on the right hand side of the page taking 250px and the main content to take whatever space is left depending on window size. Although, I want the main content to come before the navigation in the HTML, so left side then right side.

I have achieved a navigation bar on the left as follows:

```
#left {
    float:left;
    width:250px;    
    background: blue;
}

#right {
    margin-left: 250px;
    background: orange;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wz355dkr/

How can this be moved to the right, without reordering the HTML?

Comment: you want the navigation bar on the right side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change `left` to `right` in css:

```css
html,
body,
div {
  height: 100%;
}
#left {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
  background: blue;
}
#right {
  margin-right: 250px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
</div>
<div id="right">
</div>
```

Comment: I've made those changes here - the right hand side drops down?

Comment: @Sam You are missing some CSS rules and messing with `#right` and `#left`

Answer (score 1):

```css
    html,
    body,
    div {
      height: 100%;
    }
    #right {
      float: right;
      width: 250px;
      background: blue;
    }
    #left {
      background: orange;
      float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div id="right">
  hello
</div>
<div id="left">
  Content in the left hand side.
</div>
```